# Application for the Deep Web

Tags: help

as I've recently discovered Deep Web, I'm still not able to explore it well. It seems to me, however, that in order to access and view videos, one must always pay (in Bitcoin). But I would like to ask, are there any links with videos that are completely free? Or do you always have to pay to get full access to the Deep Web sites? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not ever pay for access tor site. They are mostly scams. Because they have anonymity it's easy to promise everything and deliver nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Tor search engines are spammed with various fraud sites. They have to get traffic from somewhere and search engine delivers it. To get addresses of more serious servers I recommend to check some curated directory or ask on deep web forums.

Unless you get confirmation from more sources, do not ever send money in the front.

Comment: Why post two answers? Add information to the existing one by editing it.